# Formula2 vs Formula in vba

Tags: excel, vba, formula, cell

I am using vba to edit the value of cells in excel. When i use the macro recorder, I see that excel is populating using this:

```
range("E10").select
activecell.formula2R1C1("my formula")
```

Essentially I would like to understand why excel is using this, and the application of the different formula types. Also, I would like to know which one to use.

I am using the formula function to populate a cell with an array filter function. Here is the code that I have come up with so far.

```
Range("E11").Select
ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = _
    "=FILTER('Raw Data'!C[-2],('Raw Data'!C[-4]=selecteddoctor)*('Raw Data'!C[-3]=currentcard))"
Range("E11").Select
Selection.FormulaArray = _
"=FILTER('Raw Data'!C[-2],('Raw Data'!C[-4]=selecteddoctor)*('Raw Data'!C[-3]=currentcard))"
```

selecteddoctor and current card are both named ranges from my sheet.

It is important that the formula be stored as an array function so that I do not populate the cell with a spill.

I know that I used the select function and would like to avoid that if possible. that is just the code that the macro recorder gave me.

Why did it use `Formula2R1C1`? What is the difference between `FormulaR1C1` and what i have here? Could i just use `Formula?`

a rewritten section of code that accomplishes the same thing as this block, with some explanation of changes would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I do think the duplicate will clear it for you. If not, let me know and we can re-open.

Answer (score 0):

- The difference between `Formula2R1C1` and `FormulaR1C1` is same as `Formula2` vs `Formula`. Please refers to MS doc.

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Formula vs Formula2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/cells-and-ranges/range-formula-vs-formula2?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

---

- Macro recording generates code `FormulaR1C1` or `FormulaArray`. You can use `Formula` replace `FormulaR1C1` with different formula text in coding.

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Range.FormulaR1C1 property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.formular1c1?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144137)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [Range.FormulaArray property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.formulaarray?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144133)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)